# executing link.click() event doesn't open the link

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension.

In it I'm trying to run the following simple Javascript code:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel~=next]").click();
```

But doesn't seem to work for some sites.
For example, running it on [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/7.0_Release_Notes/chap-introduction.html) to open the next page doesn't work.

I've reviewed the existing SO questions on the subject but couldn't find an answer that I understand.
Some claim this has to do with security, is it true? if so, why does it work on some sites?

Comment: How does clicking on a `<link>` tag work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you can click on a `<link>` element in the document's head tag.

Shouldn't you be clicking on the actual next link?

```
document.querySelector(".next a").click()
```

Comment: I haven't noticed that the link was inside <head /> and not <body />. Might be that's the reason it doesn't work. Thanks. I'll leave the question open for a little bit more time to see if anyone can point to the specific rule concerning this before accepting your answer.

Comment: A [`<link />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) is not a visible element....How would you click it? lol